# 404 Error Document does not work in .htaccess file

Tags: apache, .htaccess

In my .htaccess file I have: `ErrorDocument 404 "Page not found"`
However, when I go to a page that does not exist I will get the default 404 error from my browser (Chrome). I don't get the text "Page not found" which I configured.

Some other stuff I have in the .htaccess file does work as expected.

My expected result is that I get the text: "Page not found" when I go to a page that does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong syntax for defining the error document. It should be:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /error_pages/404.html
```

The second parameter needs to be the path to the error document file. See this [tutorial](http://www.htaccess-guide.com/error-documents/)